QFieldCloud data loss after synchronising, can I retrieve the lost data?
I have recently started using QFieldloud. All was working fine, I surveyed my site with all my data stored locally on my phone. I tried to synchronise/push changes to the cloud which seemed fine but the data wouldn't show on my laptop after syncing using the 'prefer cloud' option even though it said it had completed the task. I then tried to download the cloud data forom the cloud web browser (i still have these files) which still isn't showing on the laptop. I then tried to synchronise my phone data and it has synchronised the blank files and appears to have deleted my data. Is there a way to retrieve this?! I'm hoping there's a temporary back up, or maybe the web versions I downloaded may work somewhere.
Looking at the online website the changes are still pending and I have the option to 'Apply changes', but when I click this it says 'no deltas to apply'. Is there any way of getting the data through this way?

I recommend using the official QField Cloud Support - just open a ticket, they answer quite fast and are always helpful!

Thank you, I didn't realise the chat option was there in the corner! They got back to me really quickly thankfully. Cheers!

Update - Retrieved data
Realised when I pressed the ID number of the changes made shown on the webpage I could see the point details and approximate location. I sifted through them all writing them again in a new project, but at least it is not lost!
I also received a response from sending QField an online ticket, where they explained the changes weren't being accepted as I had run out of data storage. They then sent me the JSON and CSV files.
